# Asynchronous Mongo DB Inserts Causing Duplicate Key Errors; how can I correctly make async inserts?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am using the Async module within a script to asynchronously insert documents into a Mongo DB collection, however, it always gives me a duplicate key error after the first insert.  I am not providing the _id for the new documents, I wish for it to be generated by Mongo.  I am actually new to Mongo, and despite searching for clues, I cannot figure out how to do this correctly.  Any advice would be helpful.

I have an async queue which I am going to add data insert tasks to, and I have limited the concurrency to 8 inserts at a time.

```
taskQueues[collName].writeQueue = async.queue(
  function(insertData, taskCompletedCb) {
    composer.Base.Collections[collName]
      .insert(dataToInsert, { safe: true }, function (err, data) {
         if (err) dataInsertedCb(err, false);
        else dataInsertedCb(false, data);// Returns an array of the data that was inserted
      });
  }, 8);
```

I then use a loop to add the tasks, within the loop the code looks like:

```
dataToInsert = defaultData.insertable[collName];// There is no _id defined, all index field data has  been double checked, no invalid values

taskQueues[collName].writeQueue.push(dataToInsert, function(err, data) {
  if (err) queueTasksCompleteCb(err, false);
  else {
    _.each(data, function(singleDataItem) {
      dataInserted.push(singleDataItem);
    });
  }
});
```

The error I get is like:

```
{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index:     dbname.coll.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('xxx') }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  lastOp: { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 0, high_: 0 },
  connectionId: 378828,
  err: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: dbname.coll.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId(\'xxx\') }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  ok: 1 }
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I have added my code! Still had no luck with this :(